# Modeler - QNEAT3 - selected destinations instead of "all origins" to "all destinations"

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, distance-matrix

I would like to calculate the distance between points from table A (80 000 entities) , to points from table B (500 entities), filtering with a relation parent-infant (or just using a common field pointing from A to B).

Another way to explain it : I don't need to have all the distances between all the "points A" to all the "points B", but only the distances between the "points A" to the point B that is mentioned in one field from table A (relation 1 to 1).

I need to use the modeler (as I would like to be able to do it again), but I am a beginner in the modeler.  I tried with collecting "unique values" from table B + selection by attribute from table A where the common id is corresponding to B id

[image: screenshot]

Then I used the OD Matrix from layers as Table : from Point Layer A (result of the selection by attribute) to Point Layer B.

[image]

The final result is a OD matrix with 80000*500 entities. (in theory, as I tried in fact with less than 500 and less than 80000).

Do you have an idea?

Comment: So what is the question...? "Do you have an idea": about what? Providing sample data and the model you created as a strating point for testing would help - otherwise, people willing to help first have to create the whole project + data and it probably would still be not exactly as you need it.